# Linux script behaves differently on ksh in two servers

Tags: linux, ksh

Below code block is from Linux script. It provides different output in different Linux servers with same OS.

```
SECURE="YES"
if [[ !((-n "$SECURE") && (( "$SECURE" == "YES") || ("$SECURE" == "NO"))) ]]
then        
  echo -e "Validation failed for varilable SECURE: $SECURE"
else
  echo "Validation passed"
fi
```

Server-1 output:

> Validation failed for varilable SECURE: YES

Server-2 output:

> Validation passed

Not sure why output is different. Any details about this will be helpful. Thanks.

Update:
I added `#!/bin/bash` as first line in both servers and they gave same output as "Validation passed".

When I add `#!/bin/ksh` I get:

Server-1 output:

> Validation failed for varilable SECURE: YES

Server-2 output:

> syntax error: `!( ( -n "$SECURE" ) &&  ( ( "$SECURE" == "YES" ) ||  ( "$SECURE" == "NO" )))' missing expression operator

By default both servers are using ksh. Calling this command:

```
env | grep SHELL
```

shows:

```
SHELL=/bin/ksh
```

But why output is different?

Update 2:
I found that KSH version is different in two servers. One server has pdksh and another has ksh93. Can any one tell me the difference between the two versions please?

Comment: What happens if you add a space after `!`?

Comment: You should get the same answer on both servers. Maybe a typo? make this a script with `#!/bin/bash` shebang, copy it to the servers, and it should work. Your logical is really convoluted: why not simply use `if [[ $SECURE = @(YES|NO) ]]; then echo "Validation passed"; else printf 'Validation failed for variable SECURE: %q\n' "$SECURE"; fi`?

Comment: Have you check the version, are they the same in both servers?

Comment: yes, versions are same

Comment: Is the environment the same on both servers (e.g. exists a variable `$SEC` on one of the servers?)

Comment: yes. environment is same.

Comment: @choroba, yes adding space after ! makes output same in both environments. But if shell is same in both, why expression is evaluated differently?

Comment: The difference between *pdksh* ([Public Domain Korn Shell](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/pdksh/)) and *ksh93* is that *pdksh* is a clone of *ksh88*, while *ksh93* is a further development of *ksh88*. You need to put a space after the `!` and between the `((`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but...

I think [`KSH-93 Frequently Asked Questions - Q17`](http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html) has a brief answer.

> Q17.  What is pdksh and is it related to ksh or KornShell?
>
> A17.  pdksh is a public domain version of a UNIX shell that is
>     unrelated to ksh. It supports most of the 1988      KornShell language
>   features and some of the 1993 features.   **Some KornShell scripts will
>   not run with pdksh**.

Now, according to manual for ksh88, te OP's script should have worked. Maybe the parser was expecting spaces between the operators or even he may have found a bug.

Anyway, this should work in both versions (even with `SECURE=""`):

```
SECURE="YES"
if [[ "$SECURE" == "YES" || "$SECURE" == "NO" ]]
then
  echo "Validation passed"
else
  echo "Validation failed for varilable SECURE: '$SECURE'"
fi
```